# create sql server DB at c# wpf runtime errors

Tags: sql-server, wpf, c#-4.0

I'm having a lot of errors can't open connect etc. I use VS 2010 c# wpf

```
String str;
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");

str = " CREATE DATABASE "
     + " ON PRIMARY "
     + " (NAME = " + "MyDatabase_Data" + ", "
     + " FILENAME = '" + "C:\\MyDatabaseData.mdf" + "', "
     + " SIZE = 2MB,"
     + " FILEGROWTH =" + "10%" + ") "
     + " LOG ON (NAME =" + "MyDatabase_Log" + ", "
     + " FILENAME = '" + "C:\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf" + "', "
     + " SIZE = 1MB, "
     + " FILEGROWTH =" + "10%" + ") ";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
try
{
    myConn.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
}
finally
{
    if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        myConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following references:

- c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- C:\Program    Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
- c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll

In App config please inser the following fragment

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

The code:

```
var myConn = "Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master";

//The CREATE DATABASE statement failed. The primary file must be at least 3 MB to accommodate a copy of the model database.
var command = @"
CREATE DATABASE myDB
ON PRIMARY 
(
NAME = MyDatabaseData, 
FILENAME = 'C:\Temp\MyDatabaseData.mdf', 
SIZE = 3MB,
FILEGROWTH =10%
) 
LOG ON 
(
NAME =MyDatabaseLog, 
FILENAME = 'C:\Temp\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', 
SIZE = 1MB, 
FILEGROWTH =10%
)";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(myConn))
{
  try
  {
    var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

  }
}
```